# How do I remove Gridlines above data point in MPAndroidChart library?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

This is my Graph

[image: Current Graph image]

---

I want to remove the Gridlines above Data points. I just want Gridline below the data points. Also I would like the dashed line effect.

Below is what I'm doing right now.

```
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);
    chart.getXAxis().setGridLineWidth(0.5f);
    chart.getXAxis().setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLinesBehindData(true);
```

I want like this

[image: What I want]

Comment: Maybe what you want is a combined Line/Bar Chart, really?

Comment: Nope, Just add the gridline below data points not above

Comment: I have added the example of what I want.

Comment: Well, if MpAndroidChart doesn't support this, you're out of luck... but combining a line chart with a bar chart (which is supported) could result in something very similar to what you want. Just trying to think out of the box...